# Is there an API for voice recognition of a person used for authentication

Tags: java, php, android, voice-recognition

I am very new to API's and searches alot but doesn't find any thing related, I want an API for voice recognition in which the frequency of voice for a user is stored and then used as a bio-metric authentication for that user. for example a user is to register giving his voice as an input, it will be processed using an API and stores the frequency or pitch of the user to somewhere then the same user when tries to login he/she has to provide his voice, it will be match with the one given at the time of registration, if it matches user will be authenticated.
Please help me out

Comment: Did you check Google Web Speech API?

Comment: yes but it is actually speech to text, i want the value of frequency of the voice of the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library to differentiate users on the basis of Audio Input, It works pretty well for me.  https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito